# Why not to implement a Keyboard Shortcut feature?

Tags: feature-request

Often I find myself manually typing `<kbd></kbd>` tags to define a shortcut inside the editor.

Shortcuts are very essential in "Super User" context, and I think, as a formatting feature, at least in SuperUser branch of Stack Exchange should be included inside the editor's toolbar.

It's neat and looks very nice, and very readable as well improving the legibility and user-friendliness as it's harder to manually type the tags in between the keyboard key names every time.

For example, <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Shift</kbd>+<kbd>Esc</kbd> is a nice way to indicate the keyboard shortcut to launch the `Windows Task Manager` application.

Moreover, I don't know how to do its formatting with Markdown.

---

After installing the [SOX userscript](https://stackapps.com/questions/6091/stack-overflow-extras-sox) (stackapp) through [GreaseMonkey](https://addons.mozilla.org/en-US/firefox/addon/greasemonkey/) addon on Firefox (implemented as a custom JavaScript script) as suggested by [fixer1234](https://meta.superuser.com/users/364367/fixer1234) the post editor looks as depicted in the screenshot below

[image: Post editor after installing SOX]

As a fact, it also changes the Topbar looks

[image: Changed Topbar looks]

It doesn't look very neat and is hard(er) to install in terms of user-friendliness, after going through some confirmation dialogues.

Comment: I don't believe there is a way to produce that effect without the `<kbd>` markup, for what it's worth.

Answer (score 3):

Your desire has already been fulfilled.  See [SOX](https://stackapps.com/questions/6091/stack-overflow-extras-sox).  It adds 50-some improvements to the Stack Exchange UI.  This includes a number of enhancements to the post editor, one of which is automated keycap markup tags (select text, click button, <kbd>instant_keycap_formatting</kbd>).

The list of SOX features is [here](https://github.com/soscripted/sox/wiki/Features).  Installation instructions and the install link are contained in that first Stack Apps link, first line of this answer.

Comment: That's great but why not to implement those features by default, for all users, without having to install them separately?

Comment: @Chinggis6, my sentiments, exactly.